# How to apply a pagination on IBM vs code chaincode for fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

I'm using an **IBM-Blockchain platform VS code** extension for one of my **POC** development. I want pagination on the Query function in fabric. Here is my demo example:

```
let queryString = 
  { 
    "selector": {
      "isLink": isLink,
      "f_id":f_id
    }
  }
```

How can I put pagination (like when 5 data comes on the first page and then continue like another page) on this chaincode selector query which is created on the IBM-Blockchain platform? Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pagination is done using a pagination api, so suggest you take a look here
https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-1.4/api/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getQueryResultWithPagination__anchor
For the api reference. Sorry I don't know if there is any example of use of this in any of the fabric samples, if not then hopefully there are some examples in the test suite for fabric-chaincode-node on github.

Comment: David Thanks for your answer, Already, I had gone through with this article. But I'm looking for an example or any repo.

Comment: Hii David, Can I get the previous bookmark on query output? I used this method but I get only next Bookmark reference! How I get the previous reference bookmark in Query?

Comment: I've not used pagination myself. Maybe you can cache your bookmarks as you paginate through, then use a previous bookmark to go backwards ?